# JQuery UI checkbox radio stacked on top of one another instead of side by side

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, radio-button

This is my HTML

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="signals-summary-parameters-radio">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Row Filter : </legend>
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-all">All</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-all">
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-active">Active</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-active">
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-new">New</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-new">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
  <div id="signals-summary-parameters-radio-2">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Row Filter : </legend>
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-all-2">All</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-all-2">
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-active-2">Active</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-active-2">
      <label for="signals-summary-radio-new-2">New</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="signals-summary-radio-new-2">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my Javascript :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#signals-summary-parameters-radio input").checkboxradio();
  $("#signals-summary-parameters-radio-2 input").checkboxradio();
});
```

and finally my CSS :

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(30px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}
```

I have put them all together in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/7she8akw/).

I need the `display:grid` and other options in my real-world webpage (like the `container` div in the example) but it seems to cause the radio buttons to be stacked on top of one another instead of side by side.

What CSS can I add so that the radio buttons are next to one another like in the `container-2` div in my example ?

Comment: Specify width on "signals-summary-parameters-radio" element. https://jsfiddle.net/3ea0k4r6/1/ , something like   #container div {
  width:220px;
}

Comment: ok that did the trick ! not sure exactly why but still. Thanks.

Comment: can put it as an answer if you want

Comment: Glad to help. I posted answer with above solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the width on the "div" inside the container. https://jsfiddle.net/3ea0k4r6/1/

```
#container div {
  width:220px;
}
```

Comment: ended up specifying the width on the `fieldset`